# Convention for exception argument order

Tags: c#, design-patterns, .net, exceptions

Just a quick question about a design pattern for creating custom exceptions. The question is more about the order of parameters. If you can specify more data in the exception, should the parameter for it included in the constructor, come before or after the overload parameters?

Before:

```
public FooException : Exception
{
    public string Bar { get; private set; }

    public FooException(string bar) : base()
    {
        this.Bar = bar;
    }

    public FooException(string bar, string message) : base(message)
    {
        this.Bar = bar;
    }

    public FooException(string bar, string message, Exception inner) : base(message, inner)
    {
        this.Bar = bar;
    }
}
```

After:

```
public FooException : Exception
{
    public string Bar { get; private set; }

    public FooException(string bar) : base()
    {
        this.Bar = bar;
    }

    public FooException(string message, string bar) : base(message)
    {
        this.Bar = bar;
    }

    public FooException(string message, Exception inner, string bar) : base(message, inner)
    {
        this.Bar = bar;
    }
}
```

Comment: Logging is where the majority of the information should be; put another way, there isn't enough information present at the location of the exception to tell a complete story. Don't go overboard with exception annotations, they can't help as much as you might want.

Answer (score 3):

In general, not just for exceptions, you add additional parameters to the right of the signature when doing overloads. [Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms229029(v=vs.100).aspx)